# iOS Objective-C how to encode NSString character with &#xxxxx; format

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, encode

I needed to encode character to `&#xxxxx;` format such as Chinese Characters, I would like to convert a chinese character to a '&#xxxxx;' format.
I want:
a Character -> `"&#20013"`.....

anyone could help me with?? many many many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this [NSString+HTML](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m) category by [Michael Waterfall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106244/michael-waterfall).

You'll need to:

1. Add `NSString+HTML.h`, `NSString+HTML.m`, `GTMNSString+HTML.h`, and `GTMNSString+HTML.m` into your project
2. (*If you're not using ARC, skip this step*) Because NSString+HTML isn't ARC-compatible, you'll need to go to the Build Phases under your Target, find the `.m` files and add `-fno-objc-arc` under their Compiler Flags
3. `#import "NSString+HTML.h"`
4. Use as so:

   ```
   [chineseString stringByEncodingHTMLEntities]
   ```